# Add custom fields for Woocommerce registration and rearrange existing fields

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce, registration

I can add custom fields for my Woocommerce registration form, but how would I go about rearranging them with existing fields?

My default Woocommerce registration form has fields **Username**, **Email** and **Password**.

So if I add custom fields **Phone**, **First Name** and **Last name** with this code bellow they will appear before those default fields, but how can I change their order? For example I want to put Phone after password, but keep First and Last name to be first.

```
function wooc_extra_register_fields() {?>
       <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
       <label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_phone'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <p class="form-row form-row-first">
       <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <p class="form-row form-row-last">
       <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <div class="clear"></div>
       <?php
 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'wooc_extra_register_fields' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rearrange checkout field by using below code put on functions.php file:

Change priority as you want

```
add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields", "custom_override_checkout_fields", 1);
function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['priority'] = 1;
    $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['priority'] = 2;
    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['priority'] = 3;
    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['priority'] = 4;
    $fields['billing']['billing_state']['priority'] = 5;
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['priority'] = 6;
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['priority'] = 7;
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['priority'] = 8;
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['priority'] = 9;
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['priority'] = 10;
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['priority'] = 11;
    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_override_default_locale_fields' );
function custom_override_default_locale_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['state']['priority'] = 5;
    $fields['address_1']['priority'] = 6;
    $fields['address_2']['priority'] = 7;
    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out, you can change custom fields placement by using these hooks:

**woocommerce_register_form_start** – at the beginning of the form

**woocommerce_register_form** – before the “Register” button

**woocommerce_register_form_end** - after the “Register” button